# Распростране(н)о, запятые в "(,) после того(,) как"

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

1. Сколько Н пишется в "распростране(н)о"? Пример: это сейчас очень распростране(н)о.
2. Как расставить запятые: Вдруг он не захочет общаться(,) после того(,) как увидит меня, но...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Корректно: это сейчас очень распространено. В кратких страдательных причастиях пишется одно н.

Вдруг он не захочет общаться, после того как увидит меня, но... Составной союз не расчленяется, поскольку он вводит придаточное предложение.

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д. Э.

Answer (score 0):

После "общаться" запятая тоже не нужна.

Comment: Составной союз '' после того как'' вводит придаточное предложение. Запятая нужна!